# Scrum / Rally - dealing with unfinished or abandoned tasks

Tags: project-management, scrum, rally

All the documentation I've read explains in great detail how at the end of a Scrum sprint, tasks are complete, user stories are implemented, and a customer gets a demo and accepts the implementation.

What I'm unclear about is what happens when this goes wrong.

I understand that sprints are timeboxed, so you can't extend the sprint to make time to finish something. Especially when a team of newcomers to Scrum are estimating, they're likely underestimate the size of tasks. How do we deal with a task (and therefore a user story) that is incomplete when the sprint ends?

How do we deal with tasks / user stories that are abandoned; the team discovers as they embark on the work that it does not have value?

How do we deal with tasks that are thought complete, but that the customer can't accept?

I think I can imagine ad-hoc approaches to these situations when you're working with index cards (shrug your shoulders, and plan the next sprint), but what do you do in Rally (or similar) where the software forces structure upon you?

Comment: Are you mostly wondering about the mechanics so that your iteration metrics are properly gathered and Tasks/User stories don't hang around cluttering up your workspace, or is it more of a philosophical one?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [project management is now off-topic on Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343829/is-stack-overflow-an-appropriate-website-to-ask-about-project-management-issues/343841#343841). Ask these questions on [SoftwareEngineering.SE](//softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) and [ProjectManagement.SE](//pm.stackexchange.com/) instead. (You can also flag for moderator intervention to have this question migrated.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If a User Story isn't finished at the end of the sprint, then you move it to the next sprint.
2. If you discover, that a User Story has no value, DURING A SPRINT, then you should ask the product owner and/or scrum master, why it is even in the sprint. But if it happens, you close the story and the tasks and you may add other items to the current sprint.
3. If the customer doesn't accept the product of the User Story, then you have to check why he doesn't accept it. Either the acceptance criteria of the User Story is not fulfilled, in this case the User Story gets reopend and a Bug or an additional Task gets added to it. It may also be possible, that the acceptance criteria is fulfilled, but the customer has additional wishes, then a new user story has to be created and planned for the next sprints.

Answer (score 2):

What I've always done is move unfinished stories to the next Sprint.

A possibility is that a story can be broken up into two logical pieces where one is finished and the other one isn't; in that case, you split up the story and put the unfinished piece(s) in the next Sprint.

Comment: This creates a problem when using Rally for a system of record. Maybe your project is for a regulated industry (medical devices, banking) or maybe you're organization wants to ask questions about past sprints. In this case, if at the end of Sprint 1, you "move" the story into Sprint 2.  You are happy as long as you *never* go back to look at Sprint 1. If you do, then the Rally generated Sprint burndown will show a different story since there is now less stories in Sprint 1.

Comment: Scrum is, in my opinion, about managing ongoing projects, not about keeping historical records. You can do that with other tools. You may choose to export sprint data at the end of every sprint for that... But if you make user stories granular enough, it shouldn't matter much if you didn't entirely finish a given story, would it?

Comment: I'm in complete agreement with you and this is my way too. I've been lucky enough to avoid such invasive management. But some projects are regulated (medical devices or financial) and need an audit trail for regulators. Peace out brother.

Answer (score 1):

For each incomplete user story, you'll want to use the Split option to disperse the remaining work into the next iteration (or backlog).

When you split a user story, the result is an unfinished user story in the past iteration (as a historical placeholder) and a continuation of the user story in the next iteration.

for more details: https://help.rallydev.com/manage-unfinished-work